# Photoset posts not displaying animated gifs on Tumblr

Tags: html, tumblr, mustache

OK, I kind of know what the problem is, but I need to know the best solution.

I am using a heavily modified version of this theme http://kalalalani.tumblr.com/

My client has raised an issue when reblogging photosets that contain animated gifs. The source code (this part I have never touched) looks like this:

```
 {block:Photoset}
    <li class="photoset">
        {block:Photos}
            {block:HighRes}<p><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="photo"></p>{/block:HighRes}
            {block:Caption}<p>{Caption}</p>{/block:Caption}
        {/block:Photos}
        <p class="meta">
            <a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}</a>
            {block:IfShowNotes}&nbsp;/&nbsp; <a href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:IfShowNotes}
            {block:IfDisqusComments}{block:IfDisqusShortname} &nbsp;/&nbsp; <a class="dsq-comment-count" href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread">{lang:Comments}</a>{/block:IfDisqusShortname}{/block:IfDisqusComments}
            {block:ContentSource}
                &nbsp;/&nbsp; {lang:Source}: <a href="{SourceURL}">{block:SourceLogo}<img src="{WhiteLogoURL}" width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />{/block:SourceLogo}{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceTitle}{/block:NoSourceLogo}</a></p>
            {/block:ContentSource}
        </p>
    </li>
    {/block:Photoset}
```

The issue is with {PhotoURL-HighRes} for animated gifs this size of image is unlikely to exist.

So what is the default solution. I've tried {PhotoURL-500} and {PhotoURL-100} but neither seem to work.

So

1) What is the best default.

2) Is there a way to write a fallback: so use Photo-HighRes if it exists or PhotoURL-500 (or whatever the default should be) if High-Res does not exist.

TIA. 
Luke

Comment: Hmmm, I've got something working using {LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>{LinkCloseTag} instead of the {block:HighRes} block. I think I just need to add a bit of stlying for photosets now.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, having a fallback would be the most optimal solution.
Fortunately, tumblr's `{PhotoURL-HighRes}` variable already falls back on its own, and it will automatically display the highest resolution image possible for you.

If you want to display the image always, regardless of it's resolution, just use `{PhotoURL-HighRes}` as the `img src`.

What's messing up this fallback (and also your attempts at trying out other resolutions) is the `{block:HighRes}{/block:HighRes}` tag block which, according to the documentation, is only `Rendered if there is a high-res or panorama photo for a post.`

Therefore, if there is no high-res image available (as in the case for most of your client's GIFs), then the entire image node won't appear.

So all you have to do is remove the surrounding `{block:HighRes}{/block:HighRes}` tags, and the highest resolution image will always render!

From

```
{block:HighRes}<p><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="photo"></p>{/block:HighRes}
```

to this

```
<p><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="photo"></p>
```

==============

Refer to the [official documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photo-posts) for information.